# jQuery Animation and Resizing Images in IE7

Tags: jquery, animation, internet-explorer-7, jquery-animate

I'll try and keep this as simple as possible, as I think there are a few parts to it.

I'm creating a bit of Javascript that will take a number of images, animate between them, and display some supplementary information like Price, Bedrooms, Bathrooms, when the image is the focus.

The main issue I'm having is that this code all works fine, but when the images themselves actually resize, it's choppy in IE7.

You can see the demo here: http://proofs.issl.co.uk/rrv4/

(I've removed the background and foreground demo images for now, hence the broken image, but that is unrelated to this part.)

I'm starting to think that there isn't much I can do about IE7 animating slowly. It used to be the case that both the sliding movement and the image resizes were choppy, but I changed the way the slide works (setting position:relative and animating left: instead of animating margin-left:) and that seems to have helped a lot (for some reason).

But I can't think of anything similar I can do to help the animations on the images.

I've even tried doubling the animation times but it doesn't seem to make any difference - they're still choppy, just slower!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably out of luck. IE7's javascript engine and rendering engine just aren't going to make this look smooth.

If it bothers you (and it bothers me), you could just remove the animation for IE7, granted the sudden resizing might still have the same jerkiness.

Either way, this is just what you get with IE7.